# how to filter the user who's email address ending with .@abc.com from Activve directory ? also putting the output into .CSV file

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to filter the user from Active directory who's email id end with @abc.com.

the output of this should be put into an .CSV file.

Please send me the code in C#.

Thanks in Advance.

Manoj.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Please send me the code_ is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is to correct you if you are in the wrong path. Please do avoid asking questions like this.

Anyways I will give you the basic way to approach

You have to do a LDAP query to active directory, to pull the user accounts use
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*@abc.com))

When you query this using C# program with proper credentials you should get the user's UPN name ending with @abc.com.

I have made an assumption that user's mail ID and UPN name are equal. If they are different query for mail. (i.e) instead of (name=*@abc.com) use (mail=*@abc.com)